# What in my program is causing exception c0000005? (Probably a memory error)

Tags: c, arrays, exception, pointers, memory

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint-gcc.h>
#include <string.h>

int checkAnagram(char *word1, char *word2, int length){ //This function compares the two strings by storing the occurrences of their letters in a histogram, and then comparing that histogram.
    printf("test4");
    int i, n;
    int letterCount1[26], letterCount2[26];
    char letter;
    for(i=0;i<length;i++){
        letter = word1[i];
        letterCount1[letter-'a']++;
    }
    for(n=0;n<length;n++){
        letter = word2[n];
        letterCount2[letter-'a']++;
    }

    for(i=0;i<26;i++){
        for(n=0;n<26;n++){
            if(letterCount1[i]==letterCount2[n]){
                i++;
        } else {
        return 0;}
    }
}
return 1;
}

void main(){
    int length1, length2,i,n;

    scanf("%d", &length1);
    int lengthArray1[length1]; //Array used to store the length of each string (without white spaces)
    char *sentenceArray1[length1];
    char tempString[100000];
    //The array for storing the first set of sentences, and a temporary string used
    //for allocating memory in the next loop
    for(i=0;i<=length1;i++){
        fgets(tempString, 100000, stdin); //Reads the first line of input (up to and including \0), with a maximum line length which will probably be sufficient.
        sentenceArray1[i]=malloc((strlen(tempString))*sizeof(char)); //Allocates just enough memory for each string (including \0).
        int index = 0;
        for(n=0;n<(strlen(tempString));n++){
            if(tempString[n] != ' ' && tempString[n] != '.') { //Copies only from the input if the character is not a whitespace.
                sentenceArray1[i][index++]=tolower(tempString[n]);
            }
        }
        sentenceArray1[i][index] = '\0';
        lengthArray1[i]=strlen(sentenceArray1[i]);
        printf("test1\n");
    }
    scanf("%d", &length2);//Same stuff as above, now for the second set of strings.
    int lengthArray2[length2], index;
    char *sentenceArray2[length2];
    for(i=0;i<=length2;i++){
        fgets(tempString, 100000, stdin);
        sentenceArray2[i]=malloc((strlen(tempString))*sizeof(char));
        index = 0;
        for(n=0;n<(strlen(tempString));n++){
            if(tempString[n] != ' ' && tempString[n] != '.') {
                sentenceArray2[i][index++]=tolower(tempString[n]);
            }
        }
        sentenceArray2[i][index] = '\0';
        lengthArray2[i]=strlen(sentenceArray2[i]);
        printf("test2\n");
    }
    printf("test3");
    for(i=0;i<length1;i++){
        for(n=0;n<length2;n++){
            if(lengthArray2[i]==lengthArray1[i]){
                if(checkAnagram(*sentenceArray1[n],*sentenceArray2[i], length1)==1){ //Sends strings only to the checkAnagram function if they are of the same length.
                    printf("%d ",i);
                }
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Supposed input and output:
[image: I/O]

I must have messed something up with the arrays and pointers somewhere, but the limited feedback from my console + my limited experience with C programming makes it hard to locate the error. My output gets as far to print "test4" once, and then crashes with the exception given in the title.

I hope what I want to achieve is clear, but I can't be any more precise on the error, unfortunately.

Comment: You need to learn how to use a debugger. That will save you countless hours of not knowing what just happened with your program.

Comment: Just from a quick google that exception is access_violation so you are possibly trying to access some memory that you do not have access to.

Comment: If `checkAnagram()`  receives non-lowercase letters, which it appears that it can, `letterCount1[letter-'a']++` creates problems.

Comment: @chux That could very well be a problem, but how come it is not fixed with this line: tolower(tempString[n]); ?

Comment: How does that even compile? You can't use a variable in an explicit array definition (int arr[]), it must be a constant. Also you can't declare variables after an operation (declaring after scanf). Are you sure this is C?

Comment: @Thomas `tolower()` only changes uppercase letters to lower case.  If the the string has pronunciation marks, spaces, including the typical trailing `'\n'` from fgets(), they remain the same.

Comment: @SharonJDDorot it's a 'variable-length array' introduced in C99

Comment: @bolov I believe it should be mentioned somewhere that it is not ANSI C or the standard syntax. I, for once, did not know that a C compiler exists that enables it.

Comment: Change `if(tempString[n] != ' ' && tempString[n] != '.') {` to `if(isalpha(tempString[n])) {` OR `if(!isspace(tempString[n])) {` , depending on your goal.

Comment: @SharonJDDorot it is standard C. The C99 standard version.

Comment: @SharonJDDorot http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C#C99

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main error is at:

```
if(checkAnagram(*sentenceArray1[n],*sentenceArray2[i], length1)==1){
```

From the definition of `checkAnagram` it seems that it takes a `character-array`. But you are simply passing the value of the first `char` in both these arrays. So change it to:

```
if(checkAnagram(sentenceArray1[n],sentenceArray2[i], length1)==1){
```

This actually passes a pointer to the start of both the arrays. When I ran your code, and gave the input you specified it executed successfully, but the desired output wasn't coming.

Rest is up to your algorithm. Re-check it again.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a problem with:

`for(i=0;i<=length1;i++){`

You have one iteration past the array size:

`int lengthArray1[length1];`

If `length1` is 5 then `lengthArray1` has elements 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4, but your loop counts to 5. The condition should be **`i < length1`**, not `i <= length1`.

You should also use spaces around operators to make your code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
if(checkAnagram(*sentenceArray1[n],*sentenceArray2[i], length1)==1){ //Sends strings only to the checkAnagram function if they are of the same length.
```

Errors out with "Type error in argument 1 to `checkAnagram`;found `char` expected `pointer to char`.
Errors out with "Type error in argument 2 to `checkAnagram`;found `char` expected `pointer to char`.

Remove the "*" from both argument 1 & 2.